# EdiText Android InputType

Tags: android, android-edittext

Looking on input types that a EditText view can have i seen "textPersonName" and i try to search a way to (if possible) split name and surname using maybe a method like editText.getName. My question is exist a method of edittext that splits name and surname in edittext? And if don't exist the best way is to use split or else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textPersonName` is just a style option, for instance it capitalizes the first letter of each word.  It won't help you distinguish first and last names. However you can search for spaces, for instance:

```
String[] names = editText.getText().toString().split(" ");
```

The Array of Strings will have each name in a different String. If the user entered: `John Doe` you would have "John" in `names[0]` and "Doe" in `names[1]`.